# Test order of AsyncTask completion with Robolectric

Tags: android, android-asynctask, robolectric

I have a set of AsyncTasks for which I want to test behavior when completed in different orders. Can I do this with generic Robolectric functionality or do I need to mock a complex asynchronous handling my background jobs?

Simplified I mean something like:

```
trigger functionality which start taskA and taskB
assert
complete taskA
assert
complete taskB
assert

trigger functionality which start taskA and taskB
assert
complete taskB
assert
complete taskA
assert
```

Thx

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to test asynchronous code in unit tests. You can consider converting your AsyncTasks into RxJava code. There is a module for Android called [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid). You can also read an article explaining how to [Replace AsyncTask and AsyncTaskLoader with rx.Observable – RxJava Android Patterns](http://stablekernel.com/blog/replace-asynctask-asynctaskloader-rx-observable-rxjava-android-patterns/). When you read section about testability, you can notice that with RxJava you can easily convert non-blocking request into synchronous, blocking request in the following way:

```
List results = getWeatherForLargeUsCapitals().toBlocking().first();
assertEquals(12, results.size());
```

After that, your application will use asynchronous code, but your tests will be synchronous and you will be sure that assertions will be executed when request is finished.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of async tasks. As for me I would suggest to follow Piotr answer. This will make you app cleaner, maintainable and attractive.

If you decide to go with `AsyncTask` you should extract async task body and completion body to the methods. So in test you can call them in any order that you want. Of course it will require making these methods at least package visible which is not something I would to do. Because changing the code to convince the tests running is evil.